# C add hex NUL at string end without it disappearing

Tags: c, string, packet

I am making my own network packet and the protocol states that the payload should start with an space (0x20) and end with a NUL(0x00)

Imaginary payload

```
char *payload = " HELLOWORLD\x00";
```

However once I put the packet on the wire and inspect it with wireshark the packet does not end with a 00 . I understand my mistake, however I cant find a way to add 00 to a char literal without it disappearing or becoming 3030 (hex to ascii).

This is what happens to the payload

```
48 45 4c 4c 4f 57 4f 52 4c 44
```

This is what I want

```
48 45 4c 4c 4f 57 4f 52 4c 44 00
```

I used to overocome this by then later appending

```
int a = 0x00;
```

However this makes my code look worse. Any ideas ?

Comment: You could send one more byte than you are actually sending ... also the `0x20` is not shown in your output

Comment: char *payload = " HELLOWORLD\0";

Comment: Cant you modify your receiver to take care of the issue? What is absolute need to send null appended string?

Comment: overkill. just `char * x =  " HELLOWORLD"`. but you need to send one char mode so probably somewhere in your code you have `strlen(payload)` and you need `strlen(payload) + 1`

Comment: This question lacks a [mcve].

Comment: You forgot to show how you determine the size of the packet you send. Please show the relevant code.

Comment: I use strlen() but after reading your comments I understood where I did wrong

Answer (score 3):

you cannot put `\x00` in a char literal because it's the delimiter for end of C string (well you *can*, but most C string functions won't be able to see it, and there's a nul-terminator at the end anyway so why add another one ?).

That works in pure "char array" mode:

```
const char payload[] = {' ','H','E','L','L','O','W','O','R','L','D','\x00'};
```

then send with `sizeof(payload)` as length.

note that it's overkill when you can do:

```
const char *payload = " HELLOWORLD";
```

and send `payload` with a size of `strlen(payload)+1`. That will include the end-of-string terminator and the protocol will be respected.

Comment: You can put `\x00` in a string literal , the original code is allowed. The presence of another `\x00` will affect the behaviour of functions which look for a `\x00` obviously.

Comment: that's what I meant: after that you cannot use `strlen` or such

Answer (score 3):

The string created is correct and the null byte has been allocated. This is demonstrated by the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char a[] = "fred";
    char b[] = "fred\x00";
    printf("Hello World\n");
    printf("size of %d\n",sizeof(a));
    printf("size of %d\n",sizeof(b));
    return 0;
}
```

Which produces

```
Hello World
size of 5
size of 6
```

The issue is strlen() or similar will stop at the null so the added null is not included in the measurement of the length. The solution is obtain the length via another method. Unfortunately sizeof() is not a practical run time solution. Or just output the message with a length of strlen() + 1. Note that you will have a terminating null already so you do not need to add it to the string.